# header() function does not redirect

Tags: php, redirect

i am facing a problem using the php header() function. I am trying to redirect to another page after form submission. The main thing is, that it works fine on my local XAMPP server, but not on my web server hosted by strato..

I have already searched the web for solutions but not a single one applies to my problem. So there is no whitespace before my php tag, i do not ouput anything before i call the header function and there is also nothing included that can cause any problems. I've also tried to use absolute pathes to state the page i would like to redirect to. No result..

Here is the whole content of my file `redirect.php`

```
<?php
    ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        // redirect
        header("Location: register.php"); exit;  
        //echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='register.php';</script>";   
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Redirect</title> 
  </head>
  <body>    
    <form action="redirect.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is no error output on the page, instead it will stay completly blank after form submission..
The redirection via javascript is working, but is just a workaround since it will not work if javascript is disabled.. But it shows that the if-statement will be reached!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the exit after your header call.

Comment: change the button type to input and than try

Comment: I see your file, your action of the form and redirected link are all "redirect.php".

Why don't you test by header("Location: test.php"); exit; ?

Comment: @Vicky changing from `button` to `input` won't change a thing

Comment: try ob_start in the first line

Comment: check your register.php, your redirect.php is working

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to see what HTTP traffic is actually occurring. Are you getting a http 302 redirect? Is it then loading the register page? The key to debugging this is to work out where the problem is occurring, so check your http status codes.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar the url doesn't change to register.php, so it does not redirect! register.php is working fine.

Comment: @vSugumar ob_start() unfortunately doesn't change a thing

Comment: @Glubus removing exit just prevents the page from beeing blank. in this case the form is displayed again.

Comment: remove all error reporting and alert something inside the if condition

Comment: @Simba how can i see if i am getting a http 302 redirect.. i am trying to monitor the http traffic with my dev tools, but i can only see the header information. But i believe i am not getting a redirect because when i remove the exit and use the jscript line to change the page, it works!..

Comment: (I'll assume Chrome, since you didn't specify a browser). In Chrome dev tools, the Network tab shows a list of http traffic from a page load. If you're getting a redirect, the first entry will be status 301 or 302. For a quick real-life demo: If you enter a Stackoverflow page with a valid question ID but the wrong question title in the URL, it will redirect to the correct URL. Change the title in the URL of this page with the dev tools open and you should easily see the 301 redirect it does. If your page is doing something similar then your redirect is working. If not, then it isn't.

Comment: On a different tack, the other thing to check is whether you're getting any PHP errors in your server log. The number one reason for `header()` to fail is because you've already sent some other content to the browser: you can't send a header after other content, even if that content is just a single blank line. If you do this, `header()` will issue a PHP warning message and the program will continue. If you have error reporting enabled you'll see the warning on the screen. If it's switched off, you'll have to look in the server logs for the error message.

Comment: @Simba. thank you very much for your description. i don't get any message with status 301 on my page.. so the redirect does not work. But this is what i was expecting..
I am also not getting any php errors. As you can see in my post above I enabled error reporting in my php file via `ini_set` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. But there is nothing displayed..
What else can i do?

Comment: Okay. I guess you're going to have to take a more methodical approach to debugging it. What happens if you move the `header()`+`exit()` to the very first line of the program? Does it work then? What about if it's the only thing in your program? What about if you replace `header()` with `print()`?

Comment: This code works as is for me no problem. *"there is also nothing included that can cause any problems"* so I agree this is true. If you meant to say you've omitted nothing that can cause any problems, then I beg to differ. Please expand context of your code in question until you can provide a verifiable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Simba. If I replace header() with print() the text will be printed to the page after i clicked on submit. If i move header() and exit outside the if statement, doesn't matter whether its the first line or not, it does redirect me to register.php. Whats wrong there??? The header function does not seem to work in if statements!?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII. The code also works for me on my local XAMPP server. There must be something wrong with my web server configuration. But i can't figure out what it is..